# Swift: Request review is displayed regardless of which button action is clicked by the user

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an alert that is displayed to the user asking if they are enjoying the app, it has two buttons a Yes and a No. If the user clicks the Yes button the storeKits requestReview function will be called and when the user clicks the No button a feedback View controller will be displayed.

However I am calling the requestReview() function on the leaveReviewAction and it does display when the user clicks the 'Yes' button. But when the user clicks the 'No' button the requestReview prompt is shown on the feedback view controller even though it wasn't called on this button. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

Code for the two actions

```
 @IBAction func leaveReviewAction(_ sender: Any) {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}

@IBAction func giveFeedbackAction(_ sender: Any) {
  let showFeedbackVC = UIStoryboard(name: "About", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sendFeedbackVC") as? SendFeedbackVC
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: showFeedbackVC!) // Creating a navigation controller with  at the root of the navigation stack.
    self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Code for displaying the alert

```
 //feedback Alert
let feedbackAlert = UIStoryboard(name: "Recap", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "feedbackAlert") as? FeedbackAlertViewController



//Showing the feedback alert on third synced session
    private func showFeedbackAlert() {
        //For testing alert
        self.present(feedbackAlert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information, like the code used in the feedback VC and the code used to present the alert?

Comment: Hi I added the code for showing the alert and the code on the feedback vc hasn't been implemented yet but when it is displayed the Review dialog shouldn't be displayed but it is

Comment: Double check the touch up inside bindings for your buttons.  Set a breakpoint in the `leaveReviewAction` function to see if it is actually being called when you tap "no"

Comment: Is it for sure evident the feedback VC is loading, are there visual elements you setup in the storyboard that you can see?  Based on everything you said, it sounds like either the Yes button is bound to both @IBActions, or the frame of the Yes button is overlapping the No button and is actually getting pressed when you tap No.

Comment: So the Yes button action displays the app review dialog and the no button action displays the feedback view controller with the UI elements on it but when the VC is displayed it also displays the app review dialog alert

Comment: In a completely fresh install and presentation of the alert, if you click just No first, does the review dialog appear then too?  Or does it appear only after you've clicked Yes at lease once?